# Mysql join queries not returning all rows as it should

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have an event software. The first table stores individuals who signed up for an event: `EventIndividuals`. I have a second table that stores the t-shirt they selected as a gift when they attend the event: `EventIndividualShirtXref`.

When I run the following query to see how many individuals are attending the 1st event it returns 31 rows correctly:

```
SELECT Id
FROM EventIndividuals
WHERE EventId = 1
```

Then when I run my second query to pair them up with a shirt it only returns 22 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM EventIndividualShirtXref
WHERE EventIndividualId IN(SELECT Id FROM EventIndividuals WHERE EventId = 1)
```

I also tried running the next query using a join and it still only returns 22 rows:

```
SELECT esx.*
FROM EventIndividualShirtXref esx
INNER JOIN EventIndividuals ei
ON esx.EventIndividualId = ei.Id
WHERE ei.EventId = 1
```

I checked the indexing and the the columns are indexed correctly.
Is this enough info provided to figure out why the 31 rows are cut to 22?
This has never happened to me before and it makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have any people who went to `EventId = 1` who didn't select a t-shirt?

Comment: How many rows in EventIndividualShirtXref? If there are rows missing, try: `select esx.* from EventIndividualShirtXref esx right join EventIndividuals ei on esx.EventIndividualId = ei.Id where ei.EventId = 1`

Comment: Oh man. It was a long weekend and I had a brain fart. You are right. I just plain spaced on this one. I appreciate the help. Sometimes you need 2 eyes on something if you've been staring at it for too long.